# Wordpress Site Page Exists but Error 404

Tags: pages, 404-error

I created a website using Wordpress on a local server and the migrated it to an online server both manually and using the plugin Duplicator.
All went fine and I have the same configuration of the localhost site, with all the pages set correctly.
My problem is this: when I open my Website I continue to see "Page not found" and 404 errors even it the page exists and I can see it in the Wordpress page settings. 
In addition when I enter my domain a "/wp/" is added at the end, so it's like "www.mydomain.com/wp/" and I get the "Page not found" errors.
How can I resolve this issue? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

WordPress stores on the options table two urls for the site: siteurl and home.
They should be the first two entries in the options table.
Make sure that after migrating those two options match with your new domain.
Duplicator should have taken care of it but just check to make sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I checked them and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, try what @freejack said. Replace the siteurl and home from wp-options table in the database. Then delete the.HTACCESS file from the root folder & try to run the site. Once the site runs, refresh the permalink and perform a [search-replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) on the database.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your steps but when I call my "www.mydomain.com" I see a "Page not found" error instead my homepage. I tried a lot of different solutions but I can't resolve this issue. Refreshing permalink doesn't work and I searched/replaced all in the database but there are always errors. Thank you anyway!

Comment: When I visit my main page it says that the permalink is "www.mydomain.com" but when I enter it in the browser it changes in "www.mydomain.com/wp/": is that the cause of the issue?